# Black Screen at start up in ubuntu in macbook pro 2010, but can't get nomodeset

Tags: boot, screen, macbook-pro

Well I've installed ubuntu on my mac and just left ubuntu. The thing is recently something happened that made the screen go black and won't start. I know it starts just it doesn't show anything on screen.

I see that's it's a graphics card issue but I can't seem to even get to another mode or even boot from a usb drive.

I just don't know what to do I'm relatively new to linux but can anyone help me? I've tried several keys at start up but I just get the black screen.

Thank you in advance, for the advice.

Comment: Just to confirm, you see *absolutely nothing* when the system boots? No text?

Comment: Yes, I get  the symbol - like blinking, then black screen, no text whatsoever.